# Is there a way to use the filter function to remove items in the array until a condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the consonants in a string until I get to a vowel. For example the string `"glove"`, the results should be `"ove"`.

This was my attempt but it will only remove the first consonant.

```
var newStr = str.split("").splice(1, ).join("");
var removeLetter = str.split("").shift();
```

Comment: `This was my attempt`  With your attempt, what part of the code is checking if something is a vowel or a consonant?

Comment: shouldn't you check for vowels first? you are just blindy removing the first letter. if the first letter was a vowel, your code will remove it as well

Comment: Better to use Array.from instead of split to make an array from a string.

Comment: @Keith already deleted his answer that went along a different path. But I still believe that using `.filter()` is not really helpful here. The whole thing can instead be done with a simple: `str.replace(/^[^aeiou]+/i,""))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to delete all words until your condition.

```
function removeConsonantsUntilVowel(str) {
  const vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
  let index = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.includes(str[i])) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return str.substring(index);
}

const word = "glove";
const result = removeConsonantsUntilVowel(word);
console.log(result);
```

But if you do not want that way, this is other way you can do it.

```
const vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
let index = 0;
const str2 = "GLOVE"

for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
  if (vowels.includes(str2[i])) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(str2.substring(index))
```

Comment: Here is my code in stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rovjsm?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to *do something until* you need a loop. First, break your input string `"glove"` into a char array using `.split('')`, then check for each char whether it matches any of your defined vowels (`['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`). When the first vowel has been found you break the process, put your chars back together using `.join()` and return your result.

```js
const isVowel = char =>
  ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(char.toLowerCase());

const removeConsonantsUntilVowel = str => {
  let foundVowel = false;

  return str
    .split("")
    .filter(char =>
      !foundVowel
        ? !isVowel(char)
          ? false
          : (foundVowel = true)
        : true
    )
    .join("");
};

const result = removeConsonantsUntilVowel("glove");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Filter with a flag?!